# Make image transparent in ruby

Tags: ruby, image-manipulation

I was wondering if anyone could suggest to me potential libraries in ruby for manipulating jpegs? Specifically I want to make the image 50% transparent so it can act as an overlay. The image in question would be of a house and I'd like it to overlay a village image.

Just being specific about the image as the transforms may not like multiple colours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org). This [tutorial](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/Polaroid/polaroid.html) features transparency/opacity.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

Check out [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org)